# How to fix broken link articles after upgraded from 1.5 to 3.6.5 Stable

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, joomla-1.5

I upgraded from Joomla 1.5 to 3.6.5 stable and now I have many broken link on articles.

I can fix it manually one by one (I'm even fixing it) but my main concern is that the web site is a public one where anyone can write articles and there are thousand of articles written so far I need to browse.

How do I fix it automatically or faster than browsing one link at a time?

This is the web site here [link of web site](http://www.csvr.org.za/publications/publications-by-date?start=220)
and this is one of the broken link [here](http://www.csvr.org.za/component/content/138-publications/publications/1708-the-past-imperfect-exploring-northern-ireland-south-africa-and-guatemala?Itemid=2) among hundred.

Comment: Why no one is replying to my question? Have I missed something? Please can you help?

Comment: I posted this also here: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/20549/how-to-change-joomla-broken-jooma-link-to-new-one/20564#20564. It seems like you are a bit impatient and expecting answers right away. Note that there is no guarantee that answers will arrive in a timely manner if at all. But is expected from everyone to be polite and show respect to the community and the rules. Part of this is to make sure you understand how SE works [help] [tour] and try to fit in the community in a constructive way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a thought, are you using a SEF component such as Joomsef or SH404SEF? If so, this may need updating and reconfiguring to match the previous URL pattern?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on where these links are and what consistent patterns they have. For a start you could add a redirect in your htaccess, eg.

`Redirect /component/content/138-publications /publications`

So that the link example you provided would go from

```
http://www.csvr.org.za/component/content/138-publications/publications/1708-the-past-imperfect-exploring-northern-ireland-south-africa-and-guatemala?Itemid=2
```

to

```
http://www.csvr.org.za/publications/1708-the-past-imperfect-exploring-northern-ireland-south-africa-and-guatemala?Itemid=2
```

But this depends on all the 404ing publication links matching that pattern.  If you need to run some search and replace on the content table of the database then you should post some examples of how the links look therein.