# How to change Joomla broken Jooma link to new one

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

I'm stuck for about 2 hours now and can't solve this issue.

On this [page](http://csvr.org.za/programmes), there are 6 links starting by (Advocacy) and finishing by (Research) located on the Left side of the page.

I need to re-link each of these link to the correct article.

I have all the articles in place, but I'm unable to link them to they respective articles.

I tried to go to "Menu Items" but it doesn't appear to be Menu as I tried to link but have not worked.

Please can you help?

Comment: See [Joomla! doc](https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_a_menu_item_which_points_to_an_Article) to how to add new item. To edit already existing menu item is almost the same. Instead of creating a new one, simply edit an existing one and change the article to the desired one.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the menu has been created using a custom html module rather than a menu.

This is because the menu has `<div class="custom">` around it.

If you go to the module manager (extensions - modules) and search for the type `custom` then you should find it.  Here you should be able to update the links with a WYSIWYG editor.

If you have the time, it may make sense to replace this with a menu module rather than this custom html one, as that would be better practise - the content of a menu should really be in the menu manager and not here.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a menu / menu module. This is a custom html module and the links are manually hard-written. So all you need to do is to go in the module manager and search/find this particular custom html module.

You can use the filters (module type / position) - for module type you are after the term `Custom` - for position, it is that left position - if you know what it's name is.

So there you can edit inside the html code the links as you like.
However, this is going to have a menu-type usage, you might be better if you would create a new menu (name it Left Menu) and create a new menu module for this menu, and assign it to that module position - and disable/trash/delete the current module.

Answer (score -1):

You can't edit from menu manager because this is not menu.
I see this is menu called programmes and some main category is used here.

to solve this issue simple:

1. Go to article manager and find your article(s)
2. Change article category to Advocacy or Research.
3. Done

Comment: Thanks guys, It's already solved here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43371457/how-to-change-joomla-broken-jooma-link-to-new-one/43382055?noredirect=1#comment73845513_43382055)

Comment: @user8189: it's says nothing if it's already solved on another site. FYI, you should not double-posting the same question on more than 1 stackexachange site. Apart of that there are useful answers in this site which you can select as the answer that solves your problem, which posted earlier considering each post's time. To answer your question in the comment in SO - it's not only the custom class - but the whole mark up and the actual links that aren't anything close to what a menu would look like.